# random number, fade in the answer

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm *really* new to JS and not a developer by any stretch of the imagination! I've got the code setup to generate a random number for me from an input box and dropdown list. Basically start at x, choose a maximum number form the DDL and calculate a random number in between. Code came from CSS Tricks and I've tweaked it to work for me and coded up the HTML page.

All works fine, but I'd like to animate the answer. At the moment it just appears, and it's less than elegant. I'd like something as simple as fading it in. But all the functions I try cause the calc to stop working and no number appears, let alone animated. Any chance of some guidance as to where in my string of code I need the animation to go?

```
function IsNumeric(n){
return !isNaN(n);
} 

$(function(){

  $("#getit").click(function() {

      var numLow = $("#lownumber").val();
      var numHigh = $("#highnumber").val();

      var adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1;

      var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);

      if ((IsNumeric(numLow)) && (IsNumeric(numHigh)) && (parseFloat(numLow) <= parseFloat(numHigh)) && (numLow != '') && (numHigh != '')) {
        $("#randomnumber").text(numRand);
      } else {
        $("#randomnumber").text("Erm...");
      }

      return false;
  });

  $("input[type=number]").each(function(){
      $(this).data("first-click", true);
  });

  $("input[type=number]").focus(function(){

      if ($(this).data("first-click")) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).data("first-click", false);
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle with code where you tried fade ?

Comment: Of course: http://jsfiddle.net/robmason/nsyu8/. It's the last function in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Error message from the JS Console:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character  

$(#randomnumber).fade("slow");
--^
```

For selectors you have to use strings: `$("#randomnumber").fade("slow");`

Comment: Oops yes slight oversight, but still no joy.

Comment: Yep. 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } '

Comment: have you actually checked your code or just waiting for me to answer?

Comment: I was aiming for someone to help tell me why the fade function wasn't working :) The rest of the code is fine.

Comment: the javascript engine stops processing on the first error. first you have to fix the errors.